# appending data to external text file by PHP and Actionscript3

Tags: php, xml, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

```
import fl.controls.*;

var MyText:TextArea = info_txt;

var score:XML = new XML(<score/>);
score.PlayerName = "Maged";
trace(score);
```

Here I create a new XML date , I want to write these data to an external text file to use it by PHP but I don't have much information about it .

**Note i want to append to the text field n't write .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a URLRequest with the relevant path to the PHP, make a new URLVariables to contain the xml, set it as your URLRequests 'data' and set its method to POST. Make a URLLoader, add an event listener for the COMPLETE and ERROR events, then load the URLRequest with it.

check out livedocs for examples: [URLVariables](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLVariables.html), [URLLoader](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) and [URLRequest](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequest.html)

open the file, append the text then save the file in PHP. for instance with [fwrite()](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php)